# Best way to get newly created item with auto generated id in AWS dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, java

I am using DynamoDBMapper class to save my data in DynamoDB where id is auto generated.
I need to send back newly created record as response to update frontend data but the problem is, unlike other ORM framework, DynamoDBMapper save methods is not returning ID of newly created record.

If I can get newly created record ID than i can use load() method to fetch record from DB.

what is best way to get newly created record other then query or scan on table?

Comment: After you call `save()`, is the ID field on the object you passed to `save()` not updated?

Comment: ya after reading your comment, I checked, it is updating object reference that I have passed to save method. Thanks,  now its working fine..  @MarkB